# CSS set attribute to element but not to descendants

Tags: html, css

Is there a way in pure CSS of changing the color of an item but not it's descendants?

Let's say I have this category tree:

```
<ul class="my-list sub-has-contents">
  <li>No content in this branch
    <ul>
      <li>Empty leaf node</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>No content in this one either</li>
  <li class="sub-has-contents">There is content in this branch (3 items)
    <ul>
      <li class="has-contents">There is some content is this leaf node (1 item)</li>
      <li class="has-contents">More content here (2 items)</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

There are some branches and leaf nodes that have related contents.

Here is a fiddle of it:

http://jsfiddle.net/mvm542e5/

As you can see, setting the styles to:

```
.has-contents {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: blue;
}
.sub-has-contents {
  color: blue;
}
```

And I can see the nodes with contents in blue and the leaf nodes in bold.  The problem is that there are some nodes that do not have any content but they inherit the color of the parent 'li'.

How can I set the styles of a node but leave the descendants alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot set a property so that it would be exempted from inheritance, except of course when the problem is not inherited by definition.

If you set e.g. `color` on an element, then this value will be inherited by all children of that element, unless they themselves have `color` set on them. This is part of the very idea of CSS cascade. You cannot prevent it; you can just adapt to it.

Thus, you would need to set the property to those descendants that should not inherit it. It needs to be set to a specific value; there is no way to skip levels in inheritance (e.g. make an element inherit from its grandparent and not from its parent).

Comment: To potential readers: This seems to be the right answer, so I'll accept it, but the one by Scimonster and the one from indubitablee are the workarounds that I had to use in practice, so if you are looking for an alternative just read below.

Answer (score 2):

If you can ensure that items with content are tagged with some class that includes `contents` and the ones with no content has not class. You can try this:

```css
.has-contents {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: blue;
}
.sub-has-contents {
  color: blue;
}
.my-list :not([class*="contents"]) {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="my-list sub-has-contents">
  <li>No content in this branch
    <ul>
      <li>Empty leaf node</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>No content in this one either</li>
  <li class="sub-has-contents">There is content in this branch (3 items)
    <ul>
      <li class="has-contents">There is some content is this leaf node (1 item)</li>
      <li class="has-contents">More content here (2 items)</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

you want to keep in mind the order in which you place your css, like if you were painting on a canvas, you want to paint the background colors first, then add the foreground colors. in this case, your base color is green, so make all the li of .sub-has-contents green, and then make your specific ones blue:

http://jsfiddle.net/mvm542e5/4/

```
.sub-has-contents li {
    color:green;
}
.sub-has-contents .has-contents {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: blue;
}
.sub-has-contents{
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: This works, but what I wanted to achieve this passively.  The thing is that I don't really want to specify a color for empty elements, I just want to leave them as they inherit from the body.

Answer (score 1):

You could apply a selector to all descendant elements to negate the other style.

```css
.sub-has-contents * {
  color:red;
}
.has-contents {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: blue;
}
.sub-has-contents {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul class="my-list sub-has-contents">
  <li>No content in this branch
    <ul>
      <li>Empty leaf node</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>No content in this one either</li>
  <li class="sub-has-contents">There is content in this branch (3 items)
    <ul>
      <li class="has-contents">There is some content is this leaf node (1 item)</li>
      <li class="has-contents">More content here (2 items)</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```